# Limiting time spent per day on a Windows client machine

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2016, user-accounts

I know, through the use of the Logon Hours feature that you can control when a user can login in Windows. I also know that there's a way that you log them off when they hit those limits.

What I'm after is something slightly different, in that I want to allow logins within the specified times to a maximum amount of times. The use case here is a school with a finite amount of computing resources that they wish to share among all the students.

Assume we have a user Jane, with login hours set to between 08:00 and 21:00, with group policy set to auto logoff when outside those hours. I'd like to allow Jane to use a computer for, say a maximum of two hours, over the course of her allowed login times.

If this isn't possible with Windows Server natively, perhaps someone can relate an successful experience they had with a third-party piece of software that worked for them, preferably one that doesn't require being installed on each client?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know about any third-party software to achieve this, but I would simply try with a scheduled task triggered at user logon with a delayed start set to 2 hours.

Put a powershell (or batch if you prefer) script inside to force user logoff, or simply "shutdown /f /l /t 60" (60 seconds before forced logoff).

If you wish to block user from signing on again right after his logoff, that's gonna complicate things a little bit.

You could try to experiment with disabling user from domain controller side, based on text file filled with username that already logged off that day. And of course enabling all of them in the morning next day.
Or, second way, another scheduled task with instant logoff if certain file exists.
After 2 hours, before logoff, create file in user directory, and based on this file instant logoff would apply. Would be nice to add some kind of message for the user.

A little bit of a overkill, but it might work just fine for you, without any third-party software.

Comment: I would agree task scheduler is the way to go. But be careful with user tasks, because the user could simply kill the process. So make sure you're also blocking any access to the various methods to kill a process (taskkill, taskmgr, powershell, CMD, etc).